# C++ equivalent of Java's method references?

Tags: c++, c++14, method-reference

I have a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, from which I want to check whether there is at least 1 sub-vector that's empty. So I have this:

```cpp
std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& subvec)  {
     return subvec.empty();
});
```

Is there something like this in C++14?

```
std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::vector<int>::empty);
```

I tried the above syntax, which didn't work. Nor did sticking a `&` in front of the method work, as one source claimed.

Comment: whats wrong with the first version? Seems to be fine, no? Don't try to minic Java syntax in C++, its not going to end well

Comment: Trying to make C++ look like Java (or any other language) will result in 1) Buggy programs.  2) Inefficient programs, and 3) Programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.  You violated 3), and possbily 1) or 2).

Comment: Nothing glaringly wrong with it, other than that if there is indeed a shorter and (arguably) more readable way to write it, like the below example, it would be better if I could. I only bring up Java as an example, but I'm not trying to make my code Java-like.

Comment: I won't bend C++ to the point of lumbago to make it look like the bottom, but if there is native, idiomatic or other such ways to write it better, it would be useful to know.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: If you try really hard, I'm sure you could, but then you've invented your own weird dialect of C++ that nobody else will ever use, so please don't. If you're doing this in more than one place you may want to write a function that wraps this up for you into something more neat and tidy.

Comment: Lambdas are the preferred way. Sometimes it's possible to take an address of some function in the `std` namespace, but the standard forbids it, except for a very limited set of designated [addresable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction).

Comment: Just a note, reacting to your questions title. In general languages cannot be compare 1 on 1  to another. Even things that look similar might behave very differently.

Comment: Thanks for the input all. This is admittedly a bikeshed moment, but I was writing the above and the thought came to me. I'll keep it as is, and let other input stream in on this question for a while too before I close it.

Comment: @heapunderrun A lambda is not necessary, A free function will be good too. e.g. `bool is_empty_vector(const std::vector<int>& values) { return value.empty(); }; std::any_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(),is_empty_vector); }` will be fine too. Might help sometimes if you want the predicates to be unit testable ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer probably better to make `is_empty_vector()` a template, eg: `template<typename T> bool is_empty_vector(const std::vector<T>& values) { return value.empty(); }; std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), is_empty_vector<int>);` Alternatively: `template<typename Container> bool is_empty(const Container& values) { return value.empty(); }; std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), is_empty<vector<int>>);`

Comment: @JackSack -- As mentioned, even if you got this syntax to work with some really obscure and bizarre C++ code, then the tendency I have seen is for the Java person to try and make other aspects of C++ look like Java.  Basically a slow creep towards incomprehensible code that just happens to "work".

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yeah, could even make it a template and then you're basically rolling out your own `std::empty()` clone.

Comment: @Remy Certainly a possibility tool, I just wanted to point out it doesn't have to be a lambda ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer regarding the Java mention -- it's just what I remember best. I've used the same syntax in Rust to pass methods in as closures.

Comment: No big deal, just as long as you are aware ;)

Comment: lambda expressions is the readable way. Not the case with `std::vector<int>::empty` but most methods are overloaded and then passing the method directly becomes a mess.

Comment: If you want to use a named function you can simply create one `auto isEmpty = [](std::vector<int> const& v) {return std::empty(v);};` Now add that to your `any_of()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the lambda is the readable way.

Only for illustration lets explore other ways. The predicate `p` needs to be (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)):

> The expression `p(v)` must be convertible to `bool` for every argument `v` of type (possibly const) `VT`, where `VT` is the value type of `InputIt`, regardless of value category, and must not modify `v`. Thus, a parameter type of `VT&` is not allowed, nor is `VT` unless for `VT` a move is equivalent to a copy(since C++11). ​

Implicit conversions aside, this basically means, the predicate must be a callable with signature `bool (const std::vector<int>&)`.

`std::function` is a candiate. It comes with considerable overhead, because its main purpose is type erasure. We do not need type erasure, but `std::function` also has a mechanism to turn a member function pointer into a callable where the object is passed to the function. Ie we can transform `&std::vector<int>::empty`, a member function pointer, into something with signature `bool (const std::vector<int>&)`. So far so good, but this transformation isnt implicit and does not play well with class template argument deduction. As a consequence the syntax is rather clumsy:

```
int main () {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    std::any_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::function<bool(const std::vector<int>&)>(&std::vector<int>::empty));
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qdh48ax3E)

Um... We can turn the member function pointer into a callable with right signature, but `std::function` isnt really what is needed here and it does not help for terse syntax. How about writing a custom wrapper:

```
template <typename T> struct class_type;
template <typename C> struct class_type<bool(C::*)() const noexcept> { using type = C;};

template <auto F>
struct bool_member_to_functor {    
    using type = typename class_type<std::decay_t<decltype(F)>>::type;
    bool operator()(const type& c) {
        return (c.*F)();
    }
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    std::any_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(),bool_member_to_functor<&std::vector<int>::empty>{});
}
```

This leads to nice syntax on the call. Passing the member function directly is not possible, but this is as close as it can get. However, `class_type` is a bit of a cheat here. You'd need more specializations to cover all `const` / non-const, not `noexcept` etc variants. And it gets much worse when the member function is overloaded. Its not something you actually want to write.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z1M9vG813)

Conclusion: A lambda expression is the lightweight, easy to read way to wrap the member function. I doubt it can get any more readable.

Comment: One could have used `std::bind_front(&std::vector<int>::empty)` but the standard says it's unspecified behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you say:

> Nothing glaringly wrong with it, other than that if there is indeed a shorter and (arguably) more readable way to write it,

So it seems what you really want is to use named functions (a good programming practice). We can do this and still use lambdas. Just create a named lambda.

```
#include <algorithm>

auto isEmpty = [](std::vector<int> const& v)  {return v.empty(); /* or std::empty(v) */};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>   vec;

    auto f = std::any_of(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), isEmpty);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is flexible overloading rules in C++ and lack of semantics for overload set management. Member functions can be overloaded over CV as well as reference(rvalue/lvalue) qualifications of their object:

```
struct foo{
    void bar()const &;
    void bar()&&

    void bz();
};
```

Now the expression `&foo::bar` becomes ambiguous: there's one overload with a const lvalue object, as well as one with an rvalue mutable object. The only ways to disambiguate the expression are:

1. explicit casting:

```
static_cast<void (foo::*) const &()>(&foo::bar)
```

2. Or binding to object at call site, which can only be wrapped as a lambda.

If the function is not overloaded however, a function pointer can be created by taking its address: `&foo::bz` works without any problems.

For the sake of the above difficulties the `<ranges>` library - pioneered by Eric Neibler - introduced the [**Neibloid**](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/12/19/cpo-niebloid/) pattern. The idea can be implemented for any none-member functions. The article provided in the above link is not a direct answer to your question. But it is authored by a hyperactive member of C++ community and shows you lots of challenges and technicalities faced in this language.